# Error listener in loaded swf

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a swf loaded into another swf , is there a way to monitor the errors that accur in the loaded swf and trace them outside ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both SWFs are in the same security sandbox, the containing SWF can listen for events from the loaded SWF without a problem. This is probably the easiest way to implement the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: so i need to catch every error that can accur in the hosted swf and dispach an event ?  
thanks